# iOS: How to know if a mail account exist

Tags: ios, email, account

For my app, I need to know if there's a mail account has soon as the app is launched. Is there a way to do that ?

I don't really know what canSendMail does but it does not seems to verify that.

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly doesn't `canSendMail` (`MFMailComposeViewController`) work for you? As far as I'm aware, that's the only option you have.

Comment: Well I tested it on the simulator and it was always returning true. But you're right, on the device it does what I want

Comment: ya with  canSendMail you can check for the availability of wheater the account  is configured or not ..

Comment: I'm surprised that the documentation doesn't seem to mention this. The simulator will always return `YES`, because it can pretend to send mail, even though you can't actually create an email account there. It makes testing easier.

Answer (score 28):

canSendMail is actually the right and only way to verify what you want.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    // device is configured to send mail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a Xamarin solution it is available as a static property, so you can do it something like this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail
```